# como solucionar error en TRIGGER MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

Amablemente solicito su colaboracion con el siguiente error:

## 1054 - La columna 'descripcion_ant' en OLD es desconocida

Estoy tratando de crear un TRIGGER con UPDATE, este es para que antes de que se actualice  tb_productos se guarden sus registros en tb_auditoria_productos, tb_productos tiene como PRIMARY KEY cod_prod.

este es el codigo del TRIGGER  productos_BU.

```
CREATE TRIGGER productos_BU BEFORE UPDATE
ON
    tb_productos FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO tb_auditoria_productos(
        `descripcion_ant`,
        `descripcion_new`,
        `precio_costo_ant`,
        `precio_costo_new`,
        `precio_venta_ant`,
        `precio_venta_new`,
        `cantidad_ant`,
        `cantidad_new`,
        `estado_ant`,
        `estado_new`,
        `cantidad_min_ant`,
        `cantidad_min_new`,
        `cantidad_max_ant`,
        `cantidad_max_new`,
        `lote_ant`,
        `lote_new`,
        `fecha_vencimiento_ant`,
        `fecha_vencimiento_new`,
        `requiere_formula_ant`,
        `requiere_formula_new`,
        `cod_categ_prod_ant`,
        `cod_categ_prod_new`,
        `cod_tipo_prod_ant`,
        `cod_tipo_prod_new`,
        `fecha_modificacion`,
        `cod_prod`,
        `cod_usuario_accion`,
        `audi_accion`
    )
VALUES(
    old.descripcion_ant,
    NEW.descripcion_new,
    old.precio_costo_ant,
    NEW.precio_costo_new,
    old.precio_venta_ant,
    NEW.precio_venta_new,
    old.cantidad_ant,
    NEW.cantidad_new,
    old.estado_ant,
    NEW.estado_new,
    old.cantidad_min_ant,
    NEW.cantidad_min_new,
    old.cantidad_max_ant,
    NEW.cantidad_max_new,
    old.lote_ant,
    NEW.lote_new,
    old.fecha_vencimiento_ant,
    NEW.fecha_vencimiento_new,
    old.requiere_formula_ant,
    NEW.requiere_formula_new,
    old.cod_categ_prod_ant,
    NEW.cod_categ_prod_new,
    old.cod_tipo_prod_ant,
    NEW.cod_tipo_prod_new,
    NOW(), NEW.cod_prod, CURRENT_USER(), "actualizacion");
```

este es el codigo de creacion de tb_auditoria_productos , la estructura de la tabla como el TRIGGER las he formulado de diferentes formas pero siempre me sale el mismo error

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_auditoria_productos` (
  `id_audi_prod` int NOT NULL, 
  `descripcion_ant` varchar(140)   NOT NULL,
  `descripcion_new` varchar(140)   NOT NULL,
  `precio_costo_ant` int NOT NULL,
  `precio_costo_new` int NOT NULL,
  `precio_venta_ant` int NOT NULL,
  `precio_venta_new` int NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_ant` int NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_new` int NOT NULL,
  `estado_ant` varchar(15)   NOT NULL,
  `estado_new` varchar(15)   NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_min_ant` int NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_min_new` int NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_max_ant` int NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_max_new` int NOT NULL,
  `lote_ant` varchar(20)   NOT NULL,
  `lote_new` varchar(20)   NOT NULL,
  `fecha_vencimiento_ant` date NOT NULL,
  `fecha_vencimiento_new` date NOT NULL,
  `requiere_formula_ant` int NOT NULL,
  `requiere_formula_new` int NOT NULL,
  `cod_categ_prod_ant` int NOT NULL,
  `cod_categ_prod_new` int NOT NULL,
  `cod_tipo_prod_ant` int NOT NULL,
  `cod_tipo_prod_new` int NOT NULL,
  `fecha_modificacion` datetime NOT NULL,
  `cod_usuario` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,    
  `cod_usuario_accion` INT NOT NULL,
  `audi_accion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_audi_prod`)
);
```

codigo de creacion tb_productos

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_productos` (
  `cod_prod` int NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(140)   NOT NULL,
  `precio_costo` int NOT NULL,
  `precio_venta` int NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(15)   NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_min` int NOT NULL,
  `cantidad_max` int NOT NULL,
  `lote` varchar(20)   NOT NULL,
  `fecha_vencimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `requiere_formula` int NOT NULL,
  `cod_categ_prod` int NOT NULL,
  `cod_tipo_prod` int NOT NULL,
  `fecha_registro_prod` date NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`cod_prod`)
);
```

el error que sale es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su colaboracion por mas simple que sea el error,soy nuevo en esto gracias.

Comment: El error es clarísimo: **la tabla `tb_productos` no tiene una columna llamada `descripcion_ant`** ¿podrías mostrar cómo está constituida esa tabla?

Comment: El error se refiere a esta línea, que en el `TRIGGER` la escribes así: `old.descripcion_ant`, pero en la tabla `tb_productos` no hay una columna llamada `descripcion_ant`, al parecer esa columna se llama `descripcion`, entonces debes cambiarlo por `old.descripcion`. Debes entender que todo lo que tenga `old` delante se refiere a la tabla en que ocurre el `TRIGGER`, que en este caso es  `tb_productos`.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por la ayuda, se resolvio el problema, este es el primer trigger que hago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es clarísimo:

> La columna 'descripcion_ant' en OLD es desconocida

En el `TRIGGER` tienes esto:

```
old.descripcion_ant,
```

Pero la tabla `tb_productos`, donde ocurre el `TRIGGER` y que toma el alias de `old`, no hay una columna llamada `descripcion_ant`, sino que la columna se llama `descripcion`, entonces tienes que ponerlo así:

```
old.descripcion
```

Tienes que entender que todas las columnas con el pseudo `old` delante, se refieren a la tabla desde la cual se lanza el `TRIGGER`, en este caso, la tabla `tb_productos`.